# WIll a HTTPS page with video player & a video served off HTTP become insecure?

Tags: seo, https, security, video, mixed-content-security

A page is on HTTPS and all content on it is served from HTTPS, however, this page contains a video player, and once user hits a PLAY button in it, it starts playing a video, that is served from HTTP.

2 questions:

1. Will this page show a broken padlock and get insecure?
2. Will this page get SEO boost from Google (HTTPS factor)?

Comment: Both these answers are easy to Google :)

Comment: See also: [How can mixed content compromise an entire HTTPS session?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25051/how-can-mixed-content-compromise-an-entire-https-session?s=1|0.6885)

Comment: See also: [Should I fix HTTPS mixed content for SEO reasons?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81620/should-i-fix-https-mixed-content-for-seo-reasons)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller the thing is that before actually starting to play the video, it doesn't really compromise security...

Answer (score 0):

You load a resource over http. Can you be 100% sure that this is legit?
This resource might influence your page/browser, did we trust it?

As per your SEO question (which is another question really), you get a tiny bonus for having https, if used properly.